# Ajax script: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to add an ajax script to a js file so that my form works. But somehow when I post it, I get the following warning in the console:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Possibly it has something to do with the JS file. All code is wrapped in `(function($) {})` but it doesn't matter where I add my code (inside the function or outside) I keep getting the warning and the page just keeps showing the pre-loader forever.

```
$('#contact-form').submit(function() {
  var $form = $(this),
    $error = $form.find('.error-container'),
    action  = $form.attr('action');

  $error.slideUp(750, function() {
    $error.hide();
    var $name = $form.find('.form-control-name'),
      $email = $form.find('.form-control-email'),
      $phone = $form.find('.form-control-phone'),
      $message = $form.find('.form-control-message');
      // var token = grecaptcha.getResponse();

    $.post(action, {
      name: $name.val(),
      email: $email.val(),
      phone: $phone.val(),
      message: $message.val(),
      // 'g-recaptcha-response': token
    }, function(data) {
      $error.html(data);
      $error.slideDown('slow');

      if (data.match('success') != null) {
        $name.val('');
        $email.val('');
        $phone.val('');
        $message.val('');
      }
    });
  });
  return false;
});
```

What can I do about it?

I also see there is an attempt to get scripts.min.js but this file doesn't even exist in my website folder (maybe somewhere in the root, I have multiple websites on this server).

[image]

```
Ec = n.ajaxSettings.xhr();
    a.attachEvent && a.attachEvent("onunload", function() {
        for (var a in Cc) Cc[a]()
    }), k.cors = !!Ec && "withCredentials" in Ec, k.ajax = Ec = !!Ec, n.ajaxTransport(function(a) {
        var b;
        return k.cors || Ec && !a.crossDomain ? {
            send: function(c, d) {
                var e, f = a.xhr(),
                    g = ++Bc;
                if (f.open(a.type, a.url, a.async, a.username, a.password), a.xhrFields)
                    for (e in a.xhrFields) f[e] = a.xhrFields[e];
                a.mimeType && f.overrideMimeType && f.overrideMimeType(a.mimeType), a.crossDomain || c["X-Requested-With"] || (c["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest");
                for (e in c) f.setRequestHeader(e, c[e]);
                b = function(a) {
                    return function() {
                        b && (delete Cc[g], b = f.onload = f.onerror = null, "abort" === a ? f.abort() : "error" === a ? d(f.status, f.statusText) : d(Dc[f.status] || f.status, f.statusText, "string" == typeof f.responseText ? {
                            text: f.responseText
                        } : void 0, f.getAllResponseHeaders()))
                    }
                }, f.onload = b(), f.onerror = b("error"), b = Cc[g] = b("abort");
                try {
                    f.send(a.hasContent && a.data || null)
                } catch (h) {
                    if (b) throw h
                }
            },
            abort: function() {
                b && b()
            }
        } : void 0
    }), n.ajaxSetup({
        accepts: {
            script: "text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript"
        },
        contents: {
            script: /(?:java|ecma)script/
        },
        converters: {
            "text script": function(a) {
                return n.globalEval(a), a
            }
        }
```

Comment: Given that you're using `$.post` I'm guessing you've used `$.ajaxSetup()` somewhere and set `async: false` in there. You should remove that

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No this is a website template I am using, so I didn't write the JS code myself, except for the ajax script I posted in my question.

Comment: In continuation to @RoryMcCrossan comment: **Note**: The settings specified here will affect all calls to $.ajax or Ajax-based derivatives such as $.get(). This can cause undesirable behavior since other callers (for example, plugins) may be expecting the normal default settings. For that reason we strongly recommend against using this API. Instead, set the options explicitly in the call or define a simple plugin to do so.

Comment: Still, do a search in your codebase for `async: false` and remove it. You'll need to test to ensure it hasn't affected other areas of your code though. Frankly I'd have my concerns over the quality of the template you're using if they're doing something as intrinsically wrong as synchronous requests

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I searched all my JS files and there is no such line anywhere. Same for my footer (which also has a couple of lines of javascript).

Comment: `I searched all my JS files` search everything, including HTML files, because they can have `<script>` in them!! Also search the files from the `website template`, not just your code

Comment: ^ yep. Also just try searching for `async`, as the spacing may be different

Comment: If you convert to `$.post(dataObject)` call then you could set `async:true` locally within this call... https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jQuery-post-settings

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan / aromanda X I did search for async, and all files that are included in the header and footer (except for css ofcourse). It's not there.

Comment: Maybe they're using a native XMLHttpRequest so try searching for `.open(` and check for the last parameter being set to `false`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I found .open in my jquery file. But I can't figure out what the async setting is. Ill add the code in my question.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I tried deleting all my js files except for the main.js (which contains the ajax script and a lot more) and my jquery, and I still got the same result. So I changed jquery to v1.11 and v.2 and v.3 and all gave the same result. So it is probably a line in my main.js but I can't figure out what it is.